# 56198 and 57494

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

What special property is shared by 56198 and 57494 and no others?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The numbers 56198 and 57494 represent

> the only two PSE users that have earned the [Tumbleweed badge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed). The puzzle should be future-proof since the badge is retired.

Comment: Yep, you got it!

Comment: Not completely future-proof since one of those numbers no longer exists :-(